# Is there any better way to run a script as daemon which continuously polls a directory to check the presence of a file?

Tags: shell, unix

I have to continuously check if a file is present in a particular directory. I am doing this with `filecopy.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
    do
        if [ -f /var/tmp/*.*cim ]; then
            echo "Checking the file available in the path"
            mv /var/tmp/*.*cim /etc/opt/maptranslator/ss7
            /etc/init.d/ss7-stack restart
        else
            continue;
        fi
    done
```

I want the `filecopy.sh` script to run as daemon. I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in 
    start)
        /etc/init.d/filecopy.sh &
        echo $!>/var/run/filecopy.pid
    ;;
    stop)
        kill `cat /var/run/filecopy.pid`
        rm /var/run/filecopy.pid
    ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
    ;;
    status)
        if [ -e /var/run/filecopy.pid ]; then
            echo filecopy.sh is running, pid=`cat /var/run/filecopy.pid`
        else
            echo filecopy.sh is NOT running
        exit 1
        fi
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
exit 0
```

I would like to know if there is any better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Write a small C program that calls `inotify(7)`.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html or `man 7 inotify`

In this case you are waiting for `/var/tmp` to change.

However you really really shouldn't be using `/var/tmp` at all unless you want some random user to hose your protected area. File a security bug against the process that created its pid file in `/var/tmp`.